# Django with custom, non-SQL service to store models?

Tags: django, django-models

Can I have a custom service providing the storage of the models I use in Django? That service would not be speaking SQL.

I would like to build a web frontend to a system that consists of multiple services linked with a network based IPC, one of which provides an interface to commonly used, persistent objects (stored in a database).

The real question here is not whether it's possible but whether it would make sense. For example, if I end up inheriting models.Model and overwriting every single method, skipping all the rest of django.db, I guess it wouldn't.

The object service might even end up being implemented in Django, too, but the communication between it and the web frontend would not be using SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might take a look at [An introduction to using couchdb with django](http://lethain.com/entry/2008/aug/18/an-introduction-to-using-couchdb-with-django/).  Dunno if connecting to CouchDB is directly something that interests you, but this is a pretty good example of how to use django to connect to a RESTful webservice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to write a custom database backend and then use it via the DATABASE_ENGINE setting.  Models will pick it up automatically then.

I couldn't find good docs, but I'd start here:

http://djangoapi.matee.net/django.db-module.html

The Django source code is quite readable.